# Can't play Telegram ogg audio files in android

Tags: java, android, audio, ogg, telegram

I want my app play .ogg audio files from SD card, but the media player and SoundPool can't do this for some specific ogg files. The sample sound that i have problem to play belongs to Telegram. The code below works well for other ogg files and mp3 formats but gives me error when playing this type of sounds.

```
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/emulated/0/Audio/test.ogg");
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        //works good for mp3 files
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Download link of sample file:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/fxr4z4hh7b2gv50/test.ogg

it throws this exception:

```
08-27 13:50:43.244: V/MediaPlayer[Native](5163): constructor
08-27 13:50:43.245: V/MediaPlayer[Native](5163): setListener
08-27 13:50:43.245: E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI(5163): QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
08-27 13:50:43.245: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(5163): QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
08-27 13:50:43.249: V/MediaPlayer[Native](5163): setDataSource(38, 0, 576460752303423487)
08-27 13:50:43.253: V/MediaPlayer[Native](5163): message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-27 13:50:43.253: V/MediaPlayer[Native](5163): notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
08-27 13:50:43.254: E/MediaPlayer[Native](5163): Unable to create media player
08-27 13:50:43.258: W/System.err(5163): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
08-27 13:50:43.258: W/System.err(5163):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
08-27 13:50:43.258: W/System.err(5163):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1109)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1094)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1073)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1022)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at com.bobardo.funnyringtones.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:99)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
08-27 13:50:43.259: W/System.err(5163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

Comment: Does it throw the exception? Also; Were you able to play mp3 files stored in the same folder?

Comment: I edited the post, yes it throws exception. mp3 does not stored in the same directory, but i'm sure the path is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered a similar problem trying to play Telegram voice messages (see https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile and https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvoice). Not in android but in raspberry pi, although I'm guessing it could be for the same reasons.

It turns out that Telegram voice messages are [OGG](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) files encoded with [OPUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)). (maybe this is what user support_ms refers to in the latest comment to your question).

At least in ubuntu and raspbian, I didn't have the OPUS codec installed. I had to `sudo apt-get install opus-tools` in order to get the `opusdec` command line tool.

Using `opusdec` I could decode the `.ogg` file downloaded from Telegram to `.wav`, and then play it with `aplay`.

I really don't know the android equivalence to this but given your question is rather old I think this information could be of equal value to you and others trying to decode/play OPUS encoded files in *nix environments.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, you are right. telegram sounds are encoded with OPUS. so few months ago i solved my problem by using telegram open source project and the class that plays audios.